# ValueError: invalid literal for int() : while using python stream redirection

Tags: python, stdin, eoferror

I am using standard stream redirection in Python. I have a writer.py file as below.

```
for data in (123, 0, 999, 42):
    print('%03d' % data)
```

The output of it is being used as input to an addition program.

```
import sys 
sum = 0 
while True:
    try:
      line = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
    except EOFError: break
    else:
        sum += int(line)
print(sum)
```

Giving the first script's output to other as :

```
python writer.py | python adder.py
```

This gives me the error as :

```
 File "adder.py", line 9, in <module>
    sum += int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What needs to be changed in adder.py script.

Comment: Most likely because you're trying to cast a line terminator to int.

Comment: @BoboDarph, yes i too guess so. But shud 'except EOFError: break' not be able to deal with this ?

Comment: EOF happens on the next read after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **adder.py** file should look like this:

```
import sys
sum = 0
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
    if line:
        sum += int(line)
    else:
        break

print(sum)
```

I hope It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `readline()` it returns the current line of the file (stdin is treated as a file too) or returns a newline character is EOF has reached. ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

Your writer.py returns just 4 elements, but your adder.py reads input in an infinite loop so when it has read that 4 numbers, the stdin is empty and `readline()` returns a newline character, and you cannot convert a blank character to `int`. In fact, you are using `readline()[:-1]` so in your case you are getting just an empty string.

On the other hand, your print is after the infinite loop, so it will never be called (even if you stop it with a KeybordInterrupt). I suggest to use something like:

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
while line:
    #do stuff
    line = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
```

Comment: When i use this, it is skipping the first element and giving the sum of rest three elements.

Comment: @Sarang You should put the rest of the code where the "do stuff" is. The second `readline` must be at the end of the loop.
You can use a `break` instead, like rishi kant does in his solution.